# Is there a way to use the IP address in a VagrantFile that Virtualbox assigned by DHCP?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, dhcp

I am creating a VirtualBox machine with Vagrant. In the provisioning I need to know the IP address of the box that was assigned by the VirtualBox DHCP. Is there any way to use that assigned IP address in the Vagrantfile?

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # ... some more config

  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"

  # ... some more config

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    sudo -i /vagrant/my_provisioning_script.sh <insert ip here>
  SHELL
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do an `ifconfig` inside the vagrant box to get the ips of your box; should be the ip in eth0, but since you need it on the provisioning and you are using shell you could do:

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'
```

In my vagrant box this outputs

```
10.0.2.15
```

so your command could be

```
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    sudo -i /vagrant/my_provisioning_script.sh $(/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')
  SHELL
```

I tried the above with ping.

Also you can define the ip if you want, edit your Vagrantfile and add:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.23"
```

this will assign that ip to your box. and if you do `ifconfig` it will be listed on eth1. So you could hardcode the ip on your script.